# Gradle Issues When Compiling Against Android SDK Version 30.0.3

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I switched to a new development desktop (Catelina 1.15.7) forcing me to rebuild my Flutter dev environment to **Flutter 1.22.5** and **Android Studio 4.1.1**

Running ‘flutter doctor’ indicates that my environment is ok with my Android SDK version being **30.0.3**.

Having gone through a lot of Android SDK issues in the past, I changed my **./android/app/build.gradle** such that the specified sdk versions are as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30

buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
```

(The buildToolsVersion parameter was from a previous Stack Overflow post that I had hoped would resolve my issue.)

I then did a ‘flutter clean’ followed by verbose ‘flutter run’.

**My issue is that despite an explicit compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion setting of 30, the gradle build process is resulting with a task to download Android SDK Platform 29 (revision 5).**

ie- Preparing “Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)”

Does anyone know how I can get the gradle build to use Android SDK 30 instead of 29? Or is it such that the 3rd party packages used by my app has a dependency requiring Android SDK 29?

The dependencies in my pubspec.yaml are:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.1.3
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+1
  googleapis: ^0.56.1
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.12
  http: ^0.12.2
  url_launcher: ^5.7.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  tuple: ^1.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
  intl: ^0.16.1
  fraction: ^1.2.1
  archive: ^2.0.13
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  path: ^1.7.0
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
```

The Android emulator I am testing against is: **Pixel_3a_API_30_x86**.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.